# Xamarin PCL get Device Information

Tags: xamarin, device, vuzix

Hello I would like to make a project for Vuzix M300 Smart Glasses. In order to do so I need to get some information about my device in my PCL. 
I found some Xamarin Plugins which did not really solve my problem. 
So is there a way to get information about the current device like: vuzix M300 in my Visual Studio?

Comment: "some information about my device" is too vague.  What specific information do you need that the Device plugin is not providing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I found the answer by myself. 
I used the Xamarin Forms Dependency Services to get the information into the pcl. 
If you try to call the Plugin within the pcl you will get an exception.